# Can i factor out an $x^2$ while completing the square?

Tags: definite-integrals, completing-the-square

Original equation $$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{56+10x^2-x^4}}$$ 
This equation must be integrated by completing the square. My question is, when completing the square am i able to factor out $x^2$ like this $$-x^4+10x^2+56$$ $$-x^2(x^2-10)+56$$ would that be fine? and if is so how would I continue on about this with the $-x^2$ on the outside?

Comment: You would be better off putting $x^2 = t$ and then $2xdx = dt$ and then tackle the denominator with know techniques like completing square or factorise

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more I am somewhat confused. Do you mean to just replace the $x^2$ or to also break down the $x^4$ to $x^2*x^2$ as well and replace it with the $t$?

Comment: @Carlos. And after Shailesh' suggestion, first factor out the negative to get $-[t^2-10t-56]$ on which you complete the square. Then redistribute the negative. Then you arrive at something like $.....-(t-5)^2$

Comment: When you replace $x^2$ by $x$, then $x^4$ will become $t^2$.  You can use [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcTwoDIRECTORY/usubdirectory/USubstitution.html) resource to learn a little bit on this topic

Comment: @imranfat oh ok thank you that makes a lot more sense

Comment: @Shailesh thank you, I will look more into those examples.

Comment: The important thing is not what you can do, it is what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{56+10x^2-x^4}}dx$$
Using the substitution $x^2 = t$, $\,\,dt = 2xdx$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{-(t^2 -10t - 56)}}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{81-(t-5)^2}}$$ 
Substitute $s = t-5$, $\,\,ds = dt$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{ds}{\sqrt{81-s^2}}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{ds}{9\sqrt{1-\frac{s^2}{81}}}$$
Substitute $p = \frac{s}{9}$, $\,\,dp = \frac{ds}{9}$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dp}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}(p)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\Big(\frac{s}{9}\Big)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\Big(\frac{t-5}{9}\Big)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\Big(\frac{1}{9}(x^2-5)\Big)$$